# How to use this inside a function which is inside a class method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I'd like to use `this` to referring to the class properties while instead is referring to the function itself. How can I do?

```
class Person {

    isWalking = false
    steps = 10

    walk() {
        this.isWalking = setInterval(function () {
            if (this.steps <= 1) {
                clearInterval(this.isWalking)
                this.isWalking = false
            }
            --this.steps
            console.log(this.steps)
        }, 1000)
    }

}
```

Comment: Just change the callback you give to `setInterval` into an arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covert your `setInterval` callback to an arrow function

Comment: You are absolute right. I already knew that but I forgot! Thanks!